# How to periodically delete data in CockroachDB

Tags: database, system-design, cockroachdb

I am using CockroachDB for my newsletter project, and I want to delete rows every day when the data is unverified and the TTL stamp expired. It means it has to check both the "verified" field (returns bool) and the TTL stamp field (returns TIMESTAMPZ)

Issue is, the doc seems to only have specific TTL clearing function run to check the TTL stamp field only

https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/row-level-ttl

I wonder is there ways to impose conditional automated batch delete function, or simply alternatives to achieve the same effect.

Would appreciate specific code examples if possible!

Comment: And why is this tagged postgres , I would start searching fo events in cockroach

Comment: @nbk do you mind providing more details on how to use event for this use case? I am pretty new to database so I ain't familiar with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little demo of how to achieve this. In this example, I create a "basket" table to represent items in an online shopping basket and each basket has a status. Your "verified" status, is essentially my "purchased" status:

```
CREATE TYPE basket_status AS ENUM ('pending', 'purchased');

CREATE TABLE basket (
  "id" UUID PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
  "user_id" UUID NOT NULL,
  "products" STRING[] NOT NULL,
  "status" basket_status NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pending',
  "ts" TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL DEFAULT now()
) WITH (
  ttl_expiration_expression = 'CASE WHEN status = ''purchased'' THEN ((ts AT TIME ZONE ''UTC'') + INTERVAL ''1 minute'') AT TIME ZONE ''UTC'' ELSE NULL END',
  ttl_job_cron = '* * * * *'
);

INSERT INTO basket ("user_id", "products", "status") VALUES
  ('a7d16771-09d7-460d-8264-cdbd6781b005', ARRAY['a', 'b', 'c'], 'pending'),
  ('b4c38370-b493-4e44-836d-583ed8fb4dbf', ARRAY['d', 'e', 'f'], 'purchased');
```

Note that the output of `ttl_expiration_expression` must be a TIMESTAMPTZ value, hence I'm using a CASE expression to return the ts column value whne the status is "purchased"; otherwise, I return `NULL`, meaning the row is not deleted.

The inserts that follow the CREATE statement insert two items into the basket table. The first has a status of "pending", which never gets deleted, while the second has a status of "purchased", which will be deleted after around 1 minute. If you update the status of the first item to "purchased", that too will be deleted.